# PHP rename() function deletes file if already exists

Tags: php, file, rename, file-rename

I've been looking around and appearently the `// if sucess` should be executed when the file gets renamed:

`if(rename("$filepath$oldfilename", "$filepath$filename")===true) { // if success }`

Unfortunately, since this function renames the file even if another file is there with the same name, it's always a success.

But yet worse...since another file with same name already exists, it somehow gets deleted...

Anyone know a way how to prevent this? And why this is happening?!

**Additional info:**

Im giving the user the opportunity to change the file name through a textarea, when it's posted, the rename function will start:

```
        if(rename("$filepath$oldfilename", "$filepath$filename")===true)
        {
            $WhatToUpdateQueryResult = mysql_query($WhatToUpdateQuery) or die ("query fout ". mysql_error() );      

            if ($WhatToUpdateQueryResult == 1)
            {
                $uploadmsg = "Document name successfully updated.<br/> From: $oldfilename <br/> To: $filename.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $uploadmsg = "Can't update document. A file with the same name already exists.";
        }
```

*Note: As long I change the name to something which doesn't already exists, it works fine. But still, it always ends up true.*

Comment: You could check first if file exists using `file_exists()` and if exists don't update document.

Comment: "it somehow gets deleted" - the documentation for rename() explicitly states: "If newname exists, it will be overwritten."

Comment: rename is basically just the php equivalent of a shell `mv oldfile newfile`. no surprise it's "deleting" files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to make a function to check if filename already exists:

```
function rename_if_free($newPath, $oldPath) {
    if (file_exists($newPath)) return false;
    else {
        rename($oldPath, $newPath);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And put that function in your **if** statement.

Now it will be

```
if (rename_if_free($filepath.$oldfilename, $filepath.$filename) === true) { 
    $WhatToUpdateQueryResult = mysql_query($WhatToUpdateQuery) or die ("query fout ". mysql_error() );      

        if ($WhatToUpdateQueryResult == 1)
        {
            $uploadmsg = "Document name successfully updated.<br/> From: $oldfilename <br/> To: $filename.";
        }
}
else {
    $uploadmsg = "Can't update document. A file with the same name already exists.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

take `move_uploaded_file` instead. This will return false, if file can't be moved.

Edit: Ah you are not necessarily doing an upload?
Then you would have to check if the destination file already exists manually i assume. check out `file_exists()`